# How can i Download mp3 music from url in Flutter and save it in Gallery-Movies Folder or in another?

Tags: android, flutter, download, save, mp3

I have used `GallerySaver` library but this works just with `mp4`, not with `mp3`.

I've used `FlutterDownloader` and `MediaSaver` library but I don't no why isn't working to save in `Gallery` folder or in `Music` folder.

I can save in `cache` folder in app but I don't want this because I'm going to have problems later.

Can someone give me an example of this, please?